# How to wait for binding in Angular 1.5 component (without $scope.$watch)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components

I'm writing an Angular 1.5 directive and I'm running into an obnoxious issue with trying to manipulate bound data before it exists.

Here's my code:

```
app.component('formSelector', {
  bindings: {
    forms: '='
  },
  controller: function(FormSvc) {

    var ctrl = this
    this.favorites = []

    FormSvc.GetFavorites()
    .then(function(results) {
    ctrl.favorites = results
    for (var i = 0; i < ctrl.favorites.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < ctrl.forms.length; j++) {
          if (ctrl.favorites[i].id == ctrl.newForms[j].id) ctrl.forms[j].favorite = true
      }
     }
    })
}
...
```

As you can see, I'm making an AJAX call to get favorites and then checking it against my bound list of forms.

The problem is, the promise is being fulfilled even before the binding is populated... so that by the time I run the loop, ctrl.forms is still undefined!

Without using a $scope.$watch (which is part of the appeal of 1.5 components) how do I wait for the binding to be completed?

Comment: have you tried $timeout? it might trigger a lifecycle digest on its own. Or the $onInit

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could use **the new lifecycle hooks**, specifically [`$onChanges`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks), to detect the first change of a binding by calling the `isFirstChange` method. Read more about this [here](https://toddmotto.com/angular-1-5-lifecycle-hooks#using-isfirstchange).

Here's an example:

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl as $ctrl">
  <my-component binding="$ctrl.binding"></my-component>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
<script>
  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl', function($timeout) {
      $timeout(() => {
        this.binding = 'first value';
      }, 750);

      $timeout(() => {
        this.binding = 'second value';
      }, 1500);
    })
    .component('myComponent', {
      bindings: {
        binding: '<'
      },
      controller: function() {
        // Use es6 destructuring to extract exactly what we need
        this.$onChanges = function({binding}) {
          if (angular.isDefined(binding)) {
            console.log({
              currentValue: binding.currentValue, 
              isFirstChange: binding.isFirstChange()
            });
          }
        }
      }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. Angular's in a weird place right now; 1.5 is so cool and a really great option for apps that started in 1.3 or 1.4... but when you search for help on 1.5 components it's hard to sort through all the Angular 2 community chatter!

Comment: @HristoEnev Thanks! Can you tell me exactly what helped you? I'm thinking of refining the answer a bit, but I'm not sure what to emphasize: my custom method or the `$onChanges()` hook.

Comment: Your custom method. I have a two way binding and I had no idea why it is undefined on $onInit so I was wondering how to handle it's binding stabilization. This works just fine.

Comment: What happens if we don't know the type of the binding?

Comment: And what about if the binding is optional?

Comment: @HristoEnev if you don't know its type, then [angular.isUndefined](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isUndefined) would work just fine.

Comment: @HristoEnev Regarding your second question, an optional binding should only alter the functionality if it's *defined*. If it's *undefined* it mustn't break the functionality. With this in mind, once all your required bindings get stabilized, check if the optional binding is ready or not, and perform the appropriate action.

Comment: Thanks! Wish I would have found this sooner. I ran into issues attempting to use a resolve function on the routes.

Answer (score 34):

I had a similar issue, I did this to avoid calling the component until the value I am going to send is ready:

```
<form-selector ng-if="asyncValue" forms="asyncValue" ></form-selector>
```

Comment: It's an elegant solution.

Comment: @asiegfried Hm, I agree with you and at the same time feel that this is a hack. There should be an explicitly documented solution for this.

Answer (score 7):

The original poster said :

> the promise is being fulfilled even before the binding is populated...
>   sot hat by the time I run the loop, ctrl.forms is still undefined

Ever since AngularJS 1.5.3, we have [lifecycle hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) and to satisfy the OP's question, you just need to move the code that is depending on the bindings being satisfied inside `$onInit()`:

> $onInit() - Called on each controller after all the controllers on an
>   element have been constructed and had their bindings initialized (and
>   before the pre & post linking functions for the directives on this
>   element). This is a good place to put initialization code for your
>   controller.

So in the example:

```
app.component('formSelector', {
  bindings: {
    forms: '='
  },
  controller: function(FormSvc) {
    var ctrl = this;
    this.favorites = [];

    this.$onInit = function() {
      // At this point, bindings have been resolved.
      FormSvc
          .GetFavorites()
          .then(function(results) {
            ctrl.favorites = results;
            for (var i = 0; i < ctrl.favorites.length; i++) {
              for (var j = 0; j < ctrl.forms.length; j++) {
                if (ctrl.favorites[i].id == ctrl.newForms[j].id) {
                  ctrl.forms[j].favorite = true;
                }
              }
            }
          });
    }
}
```

So yes there is a `$onChanges(changesObj)`, but `$onInit()` specifically addresses the original question of when can we get a guarantee that bindings have been resolved.

Comment: I needed to get a <form> from the component's template, but within the $onInit() method the form is undefined. If I access it inside a $timeout (100ms), then I can get it properly. I do not like this approach, but accessing the form inside $onInit() is not working for me as it seems not all the bindings are resolved.

Comment: onInit does not guarantee resolved bindings.  See here: http://javascript.qahowto.com/How-to-wait-for-binding-in-Angular-15-component-without-scopewatch-javascript-angularjs-components-21fd08b which looks to be the same question.  OnChanges is the way to go, which means if you need your code to wait for valid bindings, then you will need to check that in onChanges.

Comment: I think this answers is true for 1.6 not for 1.5. $onInit does not guarantee that bindings have been resolved in 1.5 whereas 1.6 does.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I found this article very helpful.
http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2016/03/29/exploring-angular-1.5-lifecycle-hooks.html

I have an ajax call that hits the server on page load and my component needs the ajax return value to properly load. I implemented it this way:

```
this.$onChanges = function (newObj) {
      if (newObj.returnValFromAJAX)
        this.returnValFromAJAX = newObj.returnValFromAJAX;
    };
```

Now my component works perfectly. For reference I am using Angular 1.5.6

Comment: is the ajax call embedded inside your component ? or you are just passing the result as a binding?