# Angular resolve in component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, components

I have an ui.router state in which I need to resolve some data, but it seems to resolve after loading the controller and before loading the template.

State definition looks like:

```
$stateProvider
         .state( 'route', {
            url: '/update/:id',
            template: '<update order="$resolve.order"></update>',
            resolve: {
                order: function( OrdersService, $stateParams ) {
                    return OrdersService.get( $stateParams.id ).$promise
                }
            }
        } )
```

Component:

```
const Update = {
    bindings: {
       order: "<"
    },
    controller,
    template
};

angular.module( 'app' )
    .component( 'update', Update );
```

Controller:

```
export default class UpdateCtrl {
    constructor(){
         ...
         console.log(this.order);
         ...
    }
}
```

OrdersService:

```
class OrdersService {
    constructor( $resource, api_name ) {
        this.$resource = $resource( api_name + '/orders/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
            get: { method: 'GET' }
        } );
    }
    get( orderId ) {
        return this.$resource.get( { orderId } );
    }
}
angular.module( 'app' )
    .factory( 'OrdersService', [
        '$resource',
        'api_name',
        ( $resource, api_name ) => new OrdersService( $resource, api_name )
    ] );
```

All imports are fine, and I still get following from controller, and full data in template

```
console.log(this.order) // undefined
```

P.S. I found some strange behavior when I call `console.log(this.order,this)` in the controller constructor.
It prints to console

```
undefined OrderUpdateCtrl
             $stateParams:Object
             OrdersService:OrdersService
             order:Resource // full resolved object
             __proto__:Object
```

Comment: Can you please provide the implementations of  `OrdersService.get` and  controller?

Answer (score 0):

Has described in [official documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve):

> You can use `resolve` to provide your controller with content or data
>   that is custom to the state. **`resolve` is an optional map of
>   dependencies which should be injected into the controller.**

So you need to inject `order` in ui-router state's controller.

Comment: injecting into component controller gives an `Unknown provider: orderProvider <- order` error
injecting into a state controller gives no result when passing data to component through bindings

Comment: Correct.  Injecting into a component controller won't work because there is no `order` service.  If you inject into the state controller, add the line `this.order = order` to the constructor to make the data available to a component through bindings.  See my answer below.

Comment: I have updated my answer, you need to inject `order` in the controller of ui-router state `'route'` and then pass it to directive's controller .

Comment: @ByronJones @Andrea, unfortunately this doesn't work, I injected `order` into state controller and then through bindings to the component, and somehow it's still not available in controller  
`template: '<update order="resCtrl.order"></update>',`
                `controller: function( order ) {`
                 `this.order = order;`
               `},`
               `controllerAs: 'resCtrl',`
                `resolve: { ... }`

Comment: @Onefivefournine, my guess is that you are still having problems with your controller/component; see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are observing makes sense.  Your `console.log` call is inside the controller's constructor, and you do not provide an argument that Angular can use to inject `order`, making available to the constructor.

Angular is in fact resolving `order` before newing up the controller, but it can't add $resolve.order to the controller until after the controller object exists.  So `order` won't exist in the constructor function, but will exist before rendering the template.

You also have a problem with your OrdersService.  Your `get` function never passes the `id` parameter (it passes `orderId`, which isn't defined in your route).  In all likelihood, your API never gets called correctly.  Change the parameter object to `{id: orderId}`, and you should be in good shape.

Comment: oh, it's just a typo. I simplified code before I put it here

Answer (score 0):

Found answer here
[How to wait for binding in Angular 1.5 component (without $scope.$watch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639435/how-to-wait-for-binding-in-angular-1-5-component-without-scope-watch)

I should have just use the $onChanges hook to wait when promise is resolved